# @Selector and notify

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails project using react js. Below is fraction of code in the beginning of a function in one of groovy file

```
@Selector('update.intrans.info')
    def updateIntransInfoForLot(String lotNumber) {
        log.info "updateIntransInfoForLot: $lotNumber"
        def lot = Lot.findByAlotNumber(lotNumber)
...................//some code here
lot.save(flush:true)
```

I was trying to find this updateIntransInfoForLot elsewhere in the project but couldn't find. So I tried to search by

> update.intrans.info

and I found below at another groovy file.

```
notify 'update.intrans.info', lot.alotNumber
result = [type: 'lot', function: 'releaseIntransLot', arguments: [mapFields(lot)]]
```

May I know what are this @Selector and notify? How they are linked together and what is going on in this code? It will be helpful if anyone could give me a brief with website link to appropriate documentation that I can further read on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [async](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/async.html) section in the Grails docs

Answer (score 0):

Here is really simple example:

Notify:

```
def sendFromPrimaryAccount() {
    notify 'pl.stepwise.primary.mail', new MyEvent()
}
```

and source code:
https://github.com/rgorzkowski/grails-multiple-mail-senders/blob/master/grails-app/services/pl/stepwise/MailSenderService.groovy

Selector:

```
@Selector('pl.stepwise.primary.mail')
def handler(MyEvent event) {
    ....
}
```

and source code:
https://github.com/rgorzkowski/grails-multiple-mail-senders/blob/master/grails-app/services/pl/stepwise/EmailNotificationService.groovy